# How to UPDATE column based on multiple values

Tags: mysql

This case requires updating a row while NOT using the primary key. We know the `meta_key` equals `_length` AND the foreign key column is `post_id`.

We've been able to gather a list of all the post_id values but it seems there can not be 2 conditions for an UPDATE?

Here is what we are looking to achieve:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = 1 
WHERE `meta_key` = '_length' AND 
WHERE `post_id` IN (1856,1858,1943,2050)
```

If this is not possible why?

If necessary I can query to get a list of Primary Keys that match the `meta_key` = '_length' and 'post_id' IN (1856,1858,1943,2050) but it would be good to know why this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to repeat the `WHERE` for multiple conditions:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = 1 
WHERE `meta_key` = '_length' AND 
`post_id` IN (1856,1858,1943,2050)
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/where.php